# Count list items across multiple unordered lists (ul)

Tags: jquery

I have it working, but it's counting them individually. I'd like for it to continue counting through each unordered list. Thoughts? Thanks!

For instance: I have 2 unordered lists, and I want it to count through both, so if each list has 5 items, it should count up to 10 for both.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6XfkB/35/

```
function numberItems() {
    var itemCount = $('#ca-nav-wrap > li.ca-nav-list-group').find(".ca-nav-item-list > ul > li").length;
    var lihtml = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= itemCount; i++) {
        lihtml += "<li>" + i + "</li>"
    }
    $('.ca-nav-num-list ul').html(lihtml);
}
numberItems();
```

Comment: I updated my fiddle to better explain the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick.
It looks like in the last line 
`$('.ca-nav-list-num ul').html(lihtml);` 
you are finding both ul's and setting the html to what you just created so as written they will always bee the same

```
function numberItems() {
        var num = 1;
        $("li.ca-nav-list-group").each(function() {
            var itemCount = $(this).find(".ca-nav-list-item > ul > li").length;
            var lihtml = "";
            for (var i = 1; i <= itemCount; i++) {
                lihtml += "<li>" + num + "</li>" 
                num++
            }
            $(this).find('.ca-nav-list-num ul').html(lihtml);
            //$('.ca-nav-list-num ul').html(lihtml);
        });
    }
    numberItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function numberItems() {
    var count = 0;
    $("div.ca-nav-list.ca-nav-list-item > ul").each(function() {
        $("li", $(this)).each(function() {
            count += 1;
            $("div.ca-nav-list.ca-nav-list-num ul", $(this).parent().parent().parent()).append("<li>"+count+"</li>");
        });
        console.log(count);
    });
}
numberItems();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6XfkB/36/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I want it to continue counting (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) across both unordered lists.

Comment: @Smurfman82 Updated. It is soooo easy. Why you don't try it by yourself???? :'((((